# Move Node and NPM packages to offline environment

Tags: node.js

I have a node installation and many node modules installed and working on my internet machine. I need to move this to a non-internet machine.

I installed Node on the non-internet machine with no problems, but simply copy-pasting my project containing my node modules clearly was not enough. For example, I am using Gulp, and when I try to run Gulp I get `gulp is not recognized as an internal or external command`. However I can start node server itself just fine.

How do I successfully move a project with tons of npm modules from one machine to another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just running it incorrectly. Obviously when gulp being installed npm creates an alias in /url/local/bin (or whatever). This does not happen during copy/pasting. You still can run it, but you have to run it explicitly with node: `node /node_modules/gulp/app.js` (or whatever path is).

Also some modules use node-gyp to compile node extensions. Those extensions are also in node_modules, but they compiled for specific platform. If platform the same - probably no need to worry. If not - you will have to read node-gyp documentation.

Comment: Thanks!! Any idea how I can register it to work more naturally? Where do I add these aliases in windows? Or where is it found (node? windows?)

Comment: Not sure exactly, but take a look at something like https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link

Comment: To answer this: I copied my npm-cache folder from my `AppData/Roaming/npm-cache` and pasted it into my offline PC. Then I ran `npm --cache-min 9999999 install --global gulp-cli` with success!

Comment: Nice catch! This is for global. Every package can also be installed locally. If somebody will go this way after us he can consider also using only local installations.